# Orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and define an inner product on $V$ such that $$\langle A,B \rangle \colon= tr(A^tB)$$
Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ consisting of all symmetric matrices. Show that its orthogonal complement $W^{\perp}$ contains all antisymmetric matrices.

In the solution to this problem they simply show that if $A$ is antisymmetric then $tr(A^tB)=0.$

Could someone explain why this is the solution?

Comment: Do you know how $W^\perp$ is defined? They showed that if $A$ is antisymmetric then $A\in W^\perp$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ is a symmetric matrix and $A$ is an antisymmetric matrix.

$$\displaystyle
  \operatorname{tr}(SA^t)
  = \sum_{i,j}S_{ij}A_{ji}
  = -\sum_{i,j}S_{ji}A_{ij}
  = -\operatorname{tr}(S^tA)$$

Since $\operatorname{tr}(SA^t) = \operatorname{tr}(S^tA)$, we conclude that

$\langle S,A \rangle = 0$ for all $S \in W$. So $A \in W^\perp$.

Comment: Where do you get trace of $S^tA$ equals product of trace of $S$ and trace of $A$? Trace of a product isn't always the product of the traces.

Comment: @Steven Why is $tr(S^tA)=tr(S)\cdot tr(A)?$

Comment: @GerryMyerson : I fixed it.

Comment: @Si.0788 - I fixed it.

Comment: @StevenGregory Why is $tr(SA^t)=tr(S^tA)?$

Comment: @Si.0788 because If A and B are matrices such that AB is a square matrix, then trace(AB)=trace(BA).